# List only files based on their middle part using bash ls command

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am a noob in bash and have a very basic question about bash.
I have files like:

```
a_lsst_z1.5_000.txt
a_lsst_z1.5_001.txt
a_lsst90_z1.5_001.txt
a_lsst_mono_z1.5_000.txt
a_lsst_mono_z1.5_001.txt
a_lsst_mono90_z1.5_000.txt
a_lsst_mono90_z1.5_001.txt
and so on
```

I would like to list ONLY files having `lsst` not (`lsst90` or `lsst_mono`
 or `lsst_mono90`.

I have tried:

```sh
ls a_lsst_*.txt # but it gives all files
```

Required output:

```
a_lsst_z1.5_000.txt
a_lsst_z1.5_001.txt
```

How to get only **lsst** files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `ls` and exclude certain character, you can try:

```
ls a_lsst[^9m]*.txt
```

This will exclude lsst90 and lsst_mono etc files.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just match the first character after `_` as a number?

```
echo a_lsst_[0-9]*.txt
```

After your edit, you could just match the `z1.5` part:

```
echo a_lsst_z1.5_*.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ls -ltr a_lsst_z1.5_*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -iname "a_lsst_*.txt" -type f -printf %P\\n 2>/dev/null
```

gives:

```
a_lsst_mono90_z1.5_001.txt
a_lsst_z1.5_000.txt
a_lsst_z1.5_001.txt
a_lsst_mono_z1.5_000.txt
a_lsst_mono_z1.5_001.txt
a_lsst_mono90_z1.5_000.txt
```

and

```
find . -iname "a_lsst_z1*.txt" -type f -printf %P\\n 2>/dev/null
```

gives:

```
a_lsst_z1.5_000.txt
a_lsst_z1.5_001.txt
```

with `find` command in the current dir `.` and with [-iname](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Full-Name-Patterns) you'll get expected results when using the pattern  `a_lsst_*.txt` or `a_lsst_z1*.txt`.

Use [-type](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-_002dtype) f to get only match on files (not dirs).

Use [-printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-_002dprintf) with `%P` to get paths without `./` at the beginning and `\\n` to have them ended with a new line char.

`2>/dev/null` prevents from displaying any error including very common `Permission denied` when using `find` command.